# React Router with different paths on same component: does not re-initialize component (useEffect [] not called)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a Router defined on different paths using the same component, with the difference indicated via the `mode` prop.

```
<Route path="/viewAgreementForm">
    <AgreementForm mode="view" />
</Route>          
<Route path="/editAgreementForm">
    <AgreementForm mode="edit" />
</Route>
```

The `AgreementForm` does some initialization in its `useEffect(.., [])`.

Normally the routing works, but if I **go from the View mode directly to the Edit mode**, the re-initialization of the Edit-mode component doesn't work. So this section doesn't execute during the button link that takes me from View->Edit, although it does work if I open these routes independently from another screen:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.mode === 'view') {
        alert('Initializing in View Mode')
    } else {
        alert('NOT initializing in View Mode');
    }
}, []);
```

Sequence:

1. Open View mode; correctly get the View initialization
2. Click the button in the View mode that's supposed to take me to Edit.
3. I **do** get the Edit-mode version of the component correctly changed and re-rendered, but I **do not** get to the initialization of `useEffect(.., [])`, and no alerts at all.

My understanding is: the Router destroys/recreates components on any route, so I'm dealing with brand-new components, isn't that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell useEffect which variables to track,
Change to

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.mode === 'view') {
        alert('Initializing in View Mode')
    } else {
        alert('NOT initializing in View Mode');
    }
}, [props.mode]);
```

**(Note added by OP per responder's later comment:** When React sees the same component on a new route, it will act as if merely the props have changed, but will **not** create a brand-new component that would have gone through `useEffect(.., [])` (initialization.)

Comment: But don't I re-mount a new component on a router switch? It's not the same component being updated. I was under the impression that all components get destroyed & recreated on a router change.

Comment: when navigating react will get to know that you are going from `AgreementForm ` to `AgreementForm`(same component) so It will just act as if just props are changed

Comment: Thanks. For clarity, I added this important point to your answer.